# azure ml metrics using log or parent.log()?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

At the moment I am using log to track ml experiment metrics in azure. An Example of the output.

```
Run 1  mse=0.3
Run 2  mse=0.2
run 3  mse=0.1
```

However, I want one mse value that summarises the entire pipeline would  parent_run.log allow me to do this?

Research material used
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-track-designer-experiments

Answer (score 4):

totally! you can do this inside your training script you'd have

```py
from azureml.core import Run

run = Run.get_context()

run.parent.log("mse_global", 0.3)
```

See the [Remarks section of the Run class docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.run(class)?view=azure-ml-py&WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003930#remarks) for more info!

You also might want to look into `Run.log_list()` or `Run.log_table()`